# Count distinct using case when

Tags: mysql

Let me first start by saying I am new to mysql. I am transitioning from dumping data into excel and using voodoo from there so this new language can be perplexing but I am getting the hang of simple queries.

My first problem that I cannot find an answer for is that I am looking for billable medical encounters and then comparing them to how many patients were seen for that time period. (Edit: It is the "CASE WHEN statement that I am having issue with here)

Billable encounters are counted by unique encounters that can have one of any number of billable codes for that encounter to count as billable. (There are many more codes but I truncated for space)

This is what I have this far which of course is not working:

```
SELECT                   
            CONCAT(`users`.`ulname`,', ',`users`.`ufname`) AS Provider              
                      , YEAR(e.`date`) AS 'YEAR'
                      , LEFT(MONTHNAME(e.date), 3) AS 'MONTH' 
                      , COUNT(DISTINCT e.`patientID`) AS Pts
                      , COUNT(DISTINCT e.`encounterID` CASE WHEN d.`value` 
IN ('99213','99214','99212','99203','99202','90832','99393') THEN END AS 
Bill_Encs
                      , COUNT(e.`status`) AS 'Vts_CHK' 
                      , COUNT(e.`status`) - COUNT(DISTINCT e.`encounterID`) 
AS No_Codes

FROM enc e 
    INNER JOIN `mobiledoc`.`users` ON `users`.`uid` = e.`ResourceId`                
            INNER JOIN `billingdata` billing ON billing.`EncounterId` = 
e.`encounterID`
            INNER JOIN items i ON i.`itemID` = billing.`itemID`
            INNER JOIN `itemdetail` d ON d.`itemID` = i.`itemID`
 WHERE e.`date` BETWEEN CAST('2017-10-26' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-10-31' AS 
DATE)
            AND d.`propID` = 13
            AND billing.`deleteFlag` = 0
            AND i.`deleteFlag` = 0         
            AND e.status = "CHK"
            AND e.`deleteFlag` = 0
            AND e.`encType` = 1
            AND e.`ClaimReq` = 1
            AND `users`.`UserType` = 1                                               


 GROUP BY Provider ASC, YEAR(e.`date`) ,MONTH(e.`date`) ASC;
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Is there an error? Is it not providing the results you're looking for? If so, which results were you looking for and what are you getting?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is this trying to do? `COUNT(DISTINCT e.encounterID CASE WHEN d.value 
IN ('99213','99214','99212','99203','99202','90832','99393') THEN END AS 
Bill_Encs`  Additionally why join to tables Billing, items and itemdetail if no values are being selected?  Consider using an exists instead.

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'enc.date' in 'field list' is where I am stuck at. Maybe the joins are not correct. Again, I am very new to all this so I prolly complicate my queries beyond what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If all else is equal (working) I think you just want conditional aggregation.

```
, COUNT(DISTINCT e.`encounterID` CASE WHEN d.`value` 
IN ('99213','99214','99212','99203','99202','90832','99393') THEN END AS 
Bill_Encs
```

becomes

```
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.`value` 
IN ('99213','99214','99212','99203','99202','90832','99393') THEN e.`encounterID` END AS Bill_Encs
```

Comment: Solved, I had a idiot error of renaming a table and using the old name. My apologies everyone. Working fine now.

Comment: Excellent!  Don't be afraid to ask questions when you need help.  Just be sure to include a minimal complete verifiable example (MCVE).  Sample data, expected results and what you've tried and researched.  you'll get a much better response and you learn a lot along the way.